# Resumed message with custom disassembler falls in infinite loop

Tags: biztalk

I created custom pipeline component Disassembler that creates messages as follows:

```
public void ComposeMessage(Stream processingStream,
                                        Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pc,
                                        Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage inmsg,
                                        Queue msgs
                                        )
    {
        IBaseMessage outMsg = pc.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessage();
        outMsg.AddPart("Body", pc.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessagePart(), true);
        outMsg.Context = inmsg.Context;

        processingStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        outMsg.GetPart("Body").Data = processingStream;

        msgs.Enqueue(outMsg);
    }
```

Created message is being saved into file.

And it works good, however when there is an error into disassembler and message is resumed from '**BizTalk Server Administration Console**' 
it falls into infinite loop and producing huge amount of files until terminated.

I added **Debug.Write** to my code and I see that **Disassemble** method being called numerous amount of time on resumed message.

Is this normal for Biztalk ?  Is there way to change so Disassemble method will be called  once like in normal processing ?

Comment: What exactly is infinite looping?  Your code or is the message being continuously resubmitted.

Comment: from what I see standard 'Disassemble' function  (containing my code ) is being called (by Biztalk pipeline ?) in a loop. But only for suspended+resumed messages only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you throw an exception in a pipeline component you need to consume the rest of the input stream in your catch block. I think it's trying to process the remainder of the unread data stream as more messages.

Comment: Yes I do throw exception on error. How can I consume the rest of input stream ? just read it to the end ?